# Making code version aware

Tags: compatibility

[Mathics](http://www.mathics.org/), a free Mathematica-compatible project has been recently launched. It provides a subset of the functions and capabilities of Mathematica at a slower pace.

This opens us the tantalizing possibility to share our code even with people who do not have Mathematica on their computers.

Since Mathics is currently supporting only a fraction of all Mathematica functions, it becomes important for our code to be able to discriminate whether it is run within Mathematica or Mathics.

Is this possible?

Comment: Recently in Meta it was asked whether it would be appropriate to talk about Mathics. Several users (including me) thought it would be interesting, as long as Mathics language is compatible with Mathematica. So I just started the tag with this simple, but necessary question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes it is fortunately possible.
The $Version command is available in Mathics [too](http://www.mathics.net/doc/reference-of-built-in-symbols/system-functions/version/) and can clearly distinguish whether your code is running in Mathematica or Mathics, so the developer can take appropriate actions.

If you have written code/packages you might try to see if they run with Mathics and perhaps add some code to make them compatible if possible.

Comment: The documentation link is dead.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard so it seems